# How to add text unit (e.g. cm) inside input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I'm looking to put a measurement unit in my `input`, but I don't know how.
I want something like this:

> [............ cm]

This is my html:

```
    <div class="input">
     <label for="height">Height</label>
     <input id="height" type="text" value="" name="height">
    </div>
```

If I try to add a `span` next to the `input`, it just places it outside the `input`.

Comment: Inputs cannot have contents.

Comment: There must be a way to add a unit inside the input though? So the user knows in what kind of unit the input is.

Comment: an extra element positionned on the top of the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a square after the input field, you can do that manually using ::after on CSS but one of the easiest ways is to use frameworks like **bootstrap**.
You can find below a template from their website. You can also read more of this **here**: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="measurement" aria-label="measurement" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">cm</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to set `cm` at the end of your value, you could try to change the value with JavaScript.

Here is an example of how you could do it:

```js
document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
 e.target.value = e.target.value.split('cm').join('');

 if (e.target.value.slice(-2) !== 'cm') {
   e.target.value = `${e.target.value}cm`;
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" value="cm">
```

But anyway, that's not the best solution. I would recommend using placeholders, labels or maybe a tooltip to let the user know what kind of unit the input is about.